# Route with optional parameter is not working in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, routes

I am experiencing some issues with optional parameters in my routes. I think I did it properly according to the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#required-and-optional-placeholders) but still it is not working.

So I have the following route defined:

```
test_wizard:
    pattern:  /test/wizard/{testName}/{step}/
    defaults: { _controller: TestBundle:Wizard:wizard, step: 1 }
```

and would like the route to be able to be called by /test/wizard/someTestName and then fill in the step parameter with the default value of 1 but everytime I call the route just with the test name I get the following instead:

```
No route found for "GET /test/wizard/someTestName"
```

When I call the route by /test/wizard/someTestName/1/ itworks just fine. Why is my defined default value for step not working? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: try removing the last / of your route definition

Comment: Cool. That did the trick. Thanks. But now whenever I try the route /test/wizard/someTestName/1/ I got the "No route found for" message. Why is Symfony not able to handle /1 and /1/ as the same?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to make a parameter optional if you have a character after it (`/` in your case). You have to define two routes:

```
test_wizard:
    pattern:  /test/wizard/{testName}
    defaults: { _controller: TestBundle:Wizard:wizard }

test_wizard_optional:
    pattern:  /test/wizard/{testName}/{step}/
    defaults: { _controller: TestBundle:Wizard:wizard, step: 1 }
```